# Rasterio.mask returns error 'shapes are outside bounds of raster' - but they are definitely within raster bounds

Tags: python, raster, masking, rasterio

I'm using rasterio.mask.mask to mask a raster with a shapefile.

```
import rasterio
import fiona

image_object = rasterio.open('/home/cate/image_name.img')

aoi_shapefile = fiona.open('/home/cate/AOI.shp', "r")
aoi = [polygon["geometry"] for polygon in aoi_shapefile]

image_aoi, image_aoi_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(image_object, aoi)
```

and I get `UserWarning: shapes are outside bounds of raster. Are they in different coordinate reference systems?`

As far as I can tell the shape is definitely within the raster bounds..

```
image_object.bounds
BoundingBox(left=117.4095061135422, bottom=33.73209332058161, right=120.49755473423146, top=35.64128279392083)

aoi_shapefile.bounds
(119.82677788035676, 34.076577156414714, 120.37042708436398, 34.575927115244426)

image_object.crs
CRS({'init': 'epsg:4326'})

aoi_shapefile.crs
{'init': 'epsg:4326'}
```

Here is the view in QGIS:
[image]

I'm using rasterio 1.0a10 - any ideas what is happening here?

Comment: Hi Cate, I've tried to simulate this in a test I've added to the Rasterio test suite: https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/pull/1213/files#diff-e14c4c05faf427d3b98ce7a53d8c4722R244 and am unable to reproduce the problem. Can you share the .img and .shp files by any chance?

Comment: Cate, I actually have seen a similar issue in 1.0a10 in Windows, installed with conda, but haven't yet dug into it enough to file a clear bug report. I'd be curious though if you see the same behavior with 1.0a9 (I do not see this in 1.0a9).

Comment: @sgillies - no problem, the .img are shape are here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e8E4ShLai283XbcRDuXlSSXhcfiPpolZ

Comment: @jdmcbr - just rerun the same in a fresh environment (installed with pip on Ubuntu) with 1.0a9 and did NOT get the warning, mask returned a masked array as expected. I have also repeated the preprocessing of the satellite image and no errors are apparent with the original .img file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cate, this is a rasterio bug that is fixed in version 1.0a12 (on PyPI now).

`pip install --pre -U rasterio`